# Azure - How can I read cpu and memory of my web app?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-performancecounters

I'm trying to read the CPU and Memory usage for my app using `PerformanceCounters`.
code:

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;

cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
cpuCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
cpuCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
cpuCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";

var result = cpuCounter.NextValue();//ERROR HERE
```

I'm getting a Unauthorized exception.
How can I work around this?

**Edit 1:**
I tried to set the current instance name for both the processor count and the memory without luck...

**Edit 2:**
the exception `.ToString()` is

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied. at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str) at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.InternalGetValue(String name, Object defaultValue, Boolean doNotExpand, Boolean checkSecurity) at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.GetValue(String name) at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String item) at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String item) at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable() at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String category, String counter, Boolean& categoryExists) at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CounterExists(String machine, String category, String counter) at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl() at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.Initialize() at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample() at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue() at StudioTech.Web.Infrastructure.CustomMachineMonitoring.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\MMT\One\StudioTech.Web\Infrastructure\CustomMachineMonitoring.cs:line 33

Comment: Please copy the full `.ToString()` of the exception in to your question as a edit.

Comment: That is not the full `.ToString()` of the exception.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain my bad! check update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the exception information, it indicates that we have no access to Performance Monitor. As WebApp is a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), if we use the Azure WebApp, we have no access to do that.

> The user account must either be a member of the **Administrators group** or a member of the **Performance Monitor Users group** in Windows.

My suggestion is that we could use Application Insight to do that. We need to configurate Application Insight for WebApp, more details please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps). About Performance Counters in the Application Insight, we could refer to this [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters).

If we try to use Application Insight API, we need to [create a Apikey](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID). We also could get  demo code from the [document](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Metrics). It works correctly for me.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var applicationId = "xxxxxxxx";
            var applicationKey = "xxxxxxxx";
            var queryPath = "performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage";
            var queryType = "metrics";
            var str = GetTelemetry(applicationId, applicationKey, queryType, queryPath, "");


        }

 public static string GetTelemetry(string appid, string apikey,
            string queryType, string queryPath, string parameterString)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apikey);
            var req = string.Format(Url, appid, queryType, queryPath, parameterString);
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(req).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                return response.ReasonPhrase;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: the problem with the Application Insights is that its collection frequency is way too slow (once every minute) to diagnose the kind of problems i'm having... i was hoping to capture that info at least 20 times per-minute... ideally, i need it every second or less...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Application Insights is that its collection frequency could be every minute. But It seems that we have no other way to get the usage of cpu and memory for WebApp now. If we want to use customize way to get the metrics, we could use Azure VM to host the App.