# Azure web.app AI: Performance counter is not available in the web app supported list

Tags: c#, azure, clr, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure web.app (s3) that has a memory leak.
To investigate I like to add more PerformanceCounter to application insight.

But I can't make it work.

Here is my ApplicationInsights.config that I added.
(https://stebet.net/monitor-your-net-garbage-collector-using-application-insights/)

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
    <Counters>
      <Add PerformanceCounter="\.NET CLR Memory(??APP_CLR_PROC??)\# Bytes in all Heaps" ReportAs="Bytes in all Heaps" />
    </Counters>
  </Add>
```

I add my new counter to ApplicationInsights.config and deploy to azure web.app. In Portal I see no data and find error.

*AI: Performance counter is not available in the web app supported list. Counter is \Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Bytes in all Heaps.*

Please help me understand what is the problem.

Thanks,
Henrik

Comment: You could refer to the two articles, [1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4568d1a1-47f7-485e-8447-622429868452/ai-performance-counter-is-not-available-in-the-web-app-supported-list?forum=ApplicationInsights) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters#add-counters).

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. 
They help me to understand how to setup. But the problem remains that I get error in Azure and I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help me understand what is the problem.

We could get the answer from [System performance counters in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters#add-counters).

Performance counters **aren't available** for Azure Web Apps.

> Application Insights can show these performance counters if your application is running under **IIS on an on-premises host** or **virtual machine to which you have administrative access**.But you can send [Azure Diagnostics to Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-diagnostics).

But we could use Application Insight API to get data, we need to [create a Apikey](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID). We also could get demo code from the [document](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Metrics). I did a demo before, for more detail information you could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45438843/azure-how-can-i-read-cpu-and-memory-of-my-web-app/45452441#45452441).